# Last Row and Sending Values of Cell Ranges Before Printing a Copy for Each Row

Tags: vba, excel

I have found the following code that simulates the MS Word Mail Merge functionality, but exclusively in Excel cells.

It was intended to work for a single cell value for each row in a range to be sent to another cell before printing, so that several copies can be printed, each with a different name on it for rationalization, such as with printing time cards to distribute to each employee.

However, I have not been able to figure out how to apply this to sending a range of three cells (in columns **`A:C`** from Employees table) for each row to another range of three cells (**`X50:X52`** in **`Sheet1`**, instead of just the one cell.  Any ideas?

```
Sub Macro1()
   Dim lastRow As Integer '
   Dim r As Integer
   lastRow = Sheets("Employees").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

   For r = 1 To lastRow
   Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D1").Value = Sheets("Employees").Range("A" & r).Value
   ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOutNext r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Application.Transpose` to flip the row of data into a column of data.  Below I also use `Resize` to get the 3 cells from columns `A:C`.  `Resize` is much easier than try to build a range with `&` and column letters.  It returns a new `Range` that is 3 columns large instead of the 1 column from before.

```
Sub Macro1()
   Dim lastRow As Integer '
   Dim r As Integer
   lastRow = Sheets("Employees").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

   For r = 1 To lastRow
       Sheets("Sheet1").Range("X50:X52").Value = _
            Application.Transpose(Sheets("Employees").Range("A" & r).Resize(, 3).Value)

       ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOutNext r
   Next r
End Sub
```

Note that when selecting multiple cells with `Range` and calling `.Value`, you will get an array of values.  In this case, the array is 1 row by 3 columns.  `Application.Transpose` converts this data to be 3 rows by 1 column.

Comment: This is great Byron!  I no longer get the error!  The code is not actually performing the main function it was originally intended for however.  It is supposed to cycle through each row and transfer the values to the cells for each printed copy and it IS printing a copy for each record as it should, but the values for each row are not getting sent for each copy (only the values for the last record in the set of eight records is getting transferred to the cells for all eight copies).  I wanted to document that here for any future readers, but I will go ahead and post another question.  Thanks!

Comment: After looking at the code, it seems you need a `Next` in there for the loop to know what to repeat.  I just copied your code and didn't check for that.  See edit.